# Textarea Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Autocomplete="off" on textarea fields doesn't seem to work as it does with input fields. I couldn't find anything about this on Google. Is there a difference?

Specifically, I have a page that has half normal input fields, and the other half dynimically generated via javascript. When I navigate away from the page and then navigate back, the text that was in the dynamically generated fields overwrites that which is in the normal fields. This only happens when I navigate away and then click *back*. If I just refresh the page, it doesn't happen. Autocomplete="false" solved this problem for input fields, but it did not for textareas.

Comment: this sounds dependent on some javascript library you are including. show us the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `autocomplete` attribute or property is limited to `input` elements, both according to [Microsoft description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the feature and according to the [HTML5 draft description](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute) proposed to standardize the feature. So you should expect browsers to ignore it for other elements, including `textarea`.

Apparently, `autocomplete` is not the real question, just an assumed approach, which is a wrong one. But the real problem was not really described.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the problem is that the wrong text is in the textarea. I was wondering if there was a better solution than just using javascript and an extra field on the textarea after the page loads. By doing this, there is a "flash" of incorrect text as the page loads.